# Session Values getting reset after redirect rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, cookies, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using devise 3.5.1, rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0-p0.

If a user is not signed in and tries to open a private page which requires authentication, let's say `lvh.me:3000/users/1/edit`, then devise will add `users/1/edit` in session against the key `user_return_to`. The problem is that when the user gets redirected to the login page after authentication failure then `user_return_to` value in session gets reset.

I have this problem all over my app. If I store a value in session and redirect to another path from the same action then the session value disappears.

**Note:** I have upgraded my rails app from (rails 3.0.4, ruby 1.8.7) to (rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0.0).

Sorry for any ambiguities in the question. If you have any question please comment it.

**UPDATE:**

In my application controller, I've added a before filter to authenticate user. Only relevant code is shown in application controller.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :unless => :devise_controller?

  # rest of the code

end
```

I'm using a custom failure class which inherits `Devise::FailureApp`. The code looks like this.

**custom_failure.rb**

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    eval "new_user_session_path"
  end

  def redirect
    store_location!
    flash[:alert] = i18n_message
    # session[:user_return_to] returns '/foobar' here.
    redirect_to redirect_url
  end

end
```

I have commented a line in above code. session[:user_return_to] is available at that line but after the redirect on very next line, the session[:user_return_to] becomes nil.

I've upgraded devise from 1.5.3 to 3.5.1.

Comment: Can you add some code that you have used for authentication and redirection. Also I hope you have upgraded devise.

Comment: @Srikanth, you are right. I have also upgraded devise. I've updated my answer with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding the solution here in case anybody else encounters the same problem.

I had a resource named asset in my application and it was conflicting with the asset pipeline. The session was getting reset whenever my URL contained 'assets' e.g. '/assets'. So if you have a resource named asset then you have to change the prefix of your asset pipeline. To do so, add the following line in your **application.rb** file.

`config.assets.prefix = '/static_assets'`

Also you have to rename the asset pipeline folder to `static_assets`.

**Please note that this solution only applies if you have a resource named `Asset` in your application and the rails version is 3.1+**