# Losing session after a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a weird behaviour in Rails 3.2.15 where the session is lost after a redirect. The redirect is on the same domain. I pinpointed the problem to Rails.

We have an Asset model and routes like so:

```
resources :assets do
```

We call /assets/123 and in the controller there's a snippet of code like this:

```
session[:return_to] = request.url
redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
```

When inspecting session in the SessionsController, :return_to is missing.

This works on any other routes except assets. I tried changing the name of the routes and pointing it to the AssetsController and it works but it's not an option unfortunately.

I know "assets" is special in Rails because it's used for the assets pipeline. Any input on what can be done in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Try using 'path' instead of 'URL' in your method calls, and check for wildcard cookie domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272496/session-values-getting-reset-after-redirect-rails-4) on Stack Overflow. Apparently the error you're having is effectively a conflict with the asset pipeline. The question linked also points to a possible answer.